# Microsoft Teams JS SDK shareWebContent function not working on mobile app in Angular 15

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-teams-js

Hello StackOverflow community,

I'm currently developing an application using Angular 15 and the latest Microsoft Teams JavaScript SDK. I am attempting to use the **sharing.shareWebContent** function to share content in my Teams mobile app. The functionality works perfectly in the desktop version, but for some reason it's failing to work in the mobile version.

Here's a snippet of the code I'm using:

```
const shareWebContentRequest: sharing.IShareRequest<sharing.IURLContent> = {
  content: [
    {
      type: 'URL',
      url: URL, // I'm using the deep link here
      message: msgText,
      preview: false
    }
  ]
}

sharing.shareWebContent(shareWebContentRequest);
```

This code works fine in a desktop context, sharing the content as expected. However, when trying to share content in the mobile app, it doesn't work. There are no errors thrown, it simply doesn't execute the sharing operation.

I've tried various debugging steps such as confirming the SDK is correctly initialized and the **shareWebContentRequest** object is correctly formed, but I'm still facing this issue. I've also looked through the official Microsoft Teams JS SDK documentation but couldn't find any relevant information about this discrepancy between the desktop and mobile app behavior.

Has anyone else experienced this issue or can provide some insight into what might be going wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Version:  `"@microsoft/teams-js": "^2.11.0"`

Comment: Could you please share the Teams JS library version which you are using?

Comment: Could you please share the Teams JS library version which you are using?

Comment: "@microsoft/teams-js": "^2.11.0", @Nivedipa-MSFT

Answer (score 0):

Share to Teams is supported for desktop and web clients but isn't supported for mobile client.

Its already documented here: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/share-to-teams-from-personal-app-or-tab#limitations:~:text=Share%20to%20Teams%20is%20supported%20for%20desktop%20and%20web%20clients%20but%20isn%27t%20supported%20for%20mobile%20client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/share-to-teams-from-personal-app-or-tab#limitations:%7E:text=Share%20to%20Teams%20is%20supported%20for%20desktop%20and%20web%20clients%20but%20isn%27t%20supported%20for%20mobile%20client).